# ¿Por qué decimos "o sea" para expresar "es decir"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

Con frecuencia decimos "o sea" para conectar dos frases, normalmente la segunda siendo una explicación o consecuencia de la primera.

> Mañana me voy a la playa, **o sea** que nada de llamarme al móvil.

El DRAE apenas menciona lo siguiente en la entrada **ser**:

> **[ser](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm)**
>
> ( ... )
>
> ***o sea***
>
> 1. expr. es decir.

Si bien esto podría tener cierto sentido:

> 16. intr. U. para afirmar o negar en lo que se dice o pretende. Esto es.

Así que me pregunto: ¿cuál es el origen y el sentido de esta construcción? ¿Cómo una forma del tipo `<conjunción disyuntiva> + <presente del subjuntivo>` se convierte en un conector?

Además -y como siempre- ¿se usa en otros lugares que no sea España?

Comment: En Chile se usa a cada rato. También me cuestioné porqué se usa. Lo veo netamente por querer mostrar la verdadera información que se quería decir. Emplea el subjuntivo como la actitud hacia el hablante.

Comment: No conozco la respuesta, pero intuyo que puedan ir los tiros por aquí: en ciencias se usan expresiones como `sea x=1`, con el sentido de "vamos a crear una relación entre x y el valor 1". Posiblemente el _o sea_ de tu pregunta implique también la creación de una relación entre la primera parte de la frase y la segunda. Pero esto es una conjetura que me acabo de sacar de la chistera, así que no me echéis mucha cuenta.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡interesante hipótesis! Tal vez debería objetar que, en general, en España usar _o sea_ tiene cierta connotación "pija", algo alejada del campo riguroso de la ciencia. Pero, una vez más, son todo suposiciones. A mí, la parte que más me intriga es la conjunción _o_.

Comment: La "o" también sirve para establecer una relación de igualdad entre dos términos. "o. Denota equivalencia, significando 'o sea, o lo que es lo mismo'. *El protagonista, o el personaje principal de la fábula, es Hércules.*" ([RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QlqTEX0|Qlr66uc|Qltkqeu)) Es común encontrar este uso de "o" en títulos de obras clásicas. En italiano, por ejemplo, era común usar *o sia* u *ossia* con este mismo significado: *Vera storia di due amanti infelici ossia Ultime lettere di Jacopo Ortis*, de Foscolo. ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ossia/))

Comment: Yo creo que lo de @Yay da para respuesta: es una cita del DRAE. El verbo ser acentúa la equivalencia. El subjuntivo me parece más bien fósil (en el sentido de que cuando nació la expresión tenía más sentido que hoy), y concuerdo con que es un uso análogo al que se le a *sea* en matemáticas.

Comment: "O sea" es la conjunción "o" y el presente del subjuntivo del verbo ser. No hay más que explicar, el resto ya lo has dicho tú.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posibilidad es que originalmente el "*o sea*" no se haya usado para "complementar" lo que se está diciendo (mediante una aclaración, explicación, derivación o lo que sea que digamos actualmente) sino que se usara para **"autocorregir"** lo que se afirma, ofreciendo la *posibilidad* (mediante el subjuntivo "sea") de una *alternativa* (mediante la conjunción "o").

Me imagino una estructura del tipo `[Es] X, o [tal vez] sea Y`.

Los ejemplos más antiguos que pude encontrar que apoyaran esta idea fueron los siguientes:

En [Plaza universal de todas ciencias y artes: parte traducida de toscano](https://books.google.cl/books?id=P1ZvgetRDA0C&dq=%22o%20sea%22&pg=RA4-PR17#v=onepage&q=%22o%20sea%22&f=false), por Christóbal Suárez de Figueroa, 1615:

> En el descrivir, o sea delinear (hablando generalmente) intervienen burilar, barrenar, pulir...

En [Asia Portuguesa](https://books.google.cl/books?id=JHRUAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22o%20sea%22&pg=PA158#v=onepage&q=%22o%20sea%22&f=false), por Manuel Faria y Sousa, 1675:

> Salio el Sousa, y uvo una sangrienta porfia, adonde Portugueses y Castellanos (o sea Castellanos y Portugueses, porque en valor ningunos aquí fueron primeros o segundos) hizieron grandes cosas.

En estos ejemplos el "o sea" no es equivalente a "es decir", sino que se acerca más a un "*perdón, tal vez*". El paso del tiempo y la "cercanía" semántica de conceptos como "describir" y "delinear" probablemente hizo evolucionar el "o sea" hasta lexicalizarlo con un significado similar a "mejor dicho" y luego a "en otras palabras" y "vale decir".

Digo esto pensando también en el uso "titubeante" que damos en Chile al "o sea", frecuentísimo en en el discurso oral. Desconozco si se presenta en otros países. Por ejemplo:

> Ayer trajeron... o sea no, anteayer trajeron la mesa.

Aquí también se daría una especie de *marcador de autocorrección*.

Un problema de esta hipótesis es que la equivalencia "o sea = es decir" también se da al menos en portugués (*ou seja*) e italiano (*ossia*), y tendría que haber evolucionado en la misma dirección en tres dialectos distintos.

Comment: Veo que el [italiano _ossia_ aparece también entorno a principios del siglo XVII](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ossia&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cossia%3B%2Cc0), pero en ese momento ya con el significado actual ([sappere.it lo certifica](http://www.sapere.it/enciclopedia/oss%C3%ACa.html)).

Comment: Veo que Ngram no está disponible para el portugués, por lo que no puedo investigar demasiado por este lado.

Comment: De todos modos, me gusta mucho la hipótesis que elaboras: gran investigación, como estilas siempre :) La marco como aceptada. Si alguien algún día sabe más del tema, lo recomentamos. ¡Gracias!