# ¿Son las Trancas y la Bandera el mismo sitio en la frase "Victoria había nacido en las Trancas ó sea la Bandera"?

Tags: significado, historia, interpretación

> ... [Victoria] ... había vivido en la Bandera en sus primeros años, que era sumamente aficionado á la vida de vaquero y que llamaba la atención su carácter agreste y resuelto. Entre esos peones HUBO QUIÉN ASEGURÓ que **Victoria había nacido en las Trancas ó sea la Bandera**, no hace muchos años que vivía en Sataya un Sr. Berdugo que decía que él HABÍA CRIADO A VICTORIA es decir, que lo había tenido á su cuidado en su infancia.

--  C. Hernández, *Durango gráfico* (1903), p. 113

Me quedé con una duda por el "ó sea". Muy de principiante quizás, pero agradecería una aclaración de la frase. ¿Hernández afirma que las Trancas y la Bandera son el mismo sitio, o que los peones le citaron dos orígenes distintos?

Tengo otra fuente que ubica el rancho de su familia las Tracas bien lejos, en otro lugar, y por la disonancia no me he podido convencer de que sea la primera lectura, la que más me parece. Sin embargo no me sorprendería que uno de los dos autores se hubiese equivocado en la ubicación de las Trancas.

Aquí va el original escaneado:

[image: Página del libro]

Comment: «O sea» en español se usa para explicar algo en otras palabras. Aquello significa que, según el texto, son el mismo lugar o uno se ubica dentro del otro.

Comment: La primera acepción de [tranca](https://dle.rae.es/tranca#aH8utMe) en el diccionario es `Palo grueso y fuerte.`, por lo que entiendo que quizá se refiere técnicamente al mástil de la bandera, más que a la bandera (pieza de tela) en sí misma. En cualquier caso, no entiendo el texto. Aunque esas palabras con mayúscula inicial me hacen pensar que sí se habla de nombres propios (de lugares) y no de objetos, el texto carece un poco de sentido. Esa puntuación, es del texto original? Yo buscaría otras referencias de Trancas y Bandera dentro de esa obra...

Comment: @Diego No alteré la puntuación. Creo que eran ranchos; ya ubiqué a Bandera y Sataya, los dos abajo de Culiacán, Sinaloa.

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16780/6915) planteo que en el pasado _o sea_ no significaba [_A es decir B_], sino [_tal vez A y tal vez B_]. Pero es sólo una suposición.

Comment: Curioso lo que comenta @Rodrigo . Sería bueno situar en un mapa cada localidad para establecer hipótesis. A todo esto, la puntuación del texto me vuelve un poco loco, la frase de _no hace muchos años que vivía en Sataya..._ no parece tener relación con lo dicho antes, pero aparece tras una coma y me confunde muchísimo. ¿Es texto escrito o libro?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Sataya y Bandera están cercanos, es el lugar Trancas que pretendo ubicar. Ahorita puse la sección de la página arriba para verse. Creo que lo del Sr. Berdugo podría ser segunda frase, pero como sabe, a veces van y van sin parar....

Answer (score 1):

Por el poco contexto aportado, parece que el autor quiere dar a entender que Las Trancas era conocido también como La Bandera, y no así una ocurrencia de los peones

Comment: Eliminé todos los comentarios sobre las correcciones ortográficas porque no aportan a la respuesta. Para eso existe la posibilidad que tienes de editar la pregunta y ahí puedes hacer las correcciones que consideres pertinentes. Luego el dueño de la pregunta puede aprobar o rechazar las correcciones. Además nota que muchas de tus observaciones hacen referencia a un contenido citado de algún texto histórico y por lo tanto debe citarse sin cambiarlo.

Comment: Coincido con @DGaleano. Además, nótese que está citando literalmente un texto de 1903, cuando las reglas ortográficas eran algo diferentes. En cuanto a la respuesta en sí, estoy de acuerdo, si bien el comentario de Rodrigo en la pregunta me hace dudar.